# graphql-ruby, Date or Datetime type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, graphql, graphql-ruby

I'm not the only one who doesn't know how to use `Datetime` types with GraphQL-Ruby: https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby-demo/issues/27, as you can see there are 18 people like me.

How can I use Datetime to some fields like this?

```
Types::PlayerType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Player'

  field :id, !types.ID
  field :birth_date, types.Datetime #or what?
  field :death_date, !types.Datetime #or what?
  field :note, types.String
end
```

Maybe I have to use this (https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-ruby/blob/master/app/graphql/types/date_time_type.rb):

**date_time_type.rb**:

```
Types::DateTimeType = GraphQL::ScalarType.define do
  name 'DateTime'

  coerce_input ->(value, _ctx) { Time.zone.parse(value) }
  coerce_result ->(value, _ctx) { value.utc.iso8601 }
end
```

**Can someone explain it better?**

Answer (score 31):

`GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime` and `GraphQL::Types::ISO8601Date` recently got added to graphql ruby library ([Pull Request](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/pull/2471)).

Usage example:

```
field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: false
field :starts_on, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601Date, null: false
```

Answer (score 2):

The type declaration should properly work. Keep in mind that the DateTimeType you pasted is in the module "Types". Use it like this:

```
Types::PlayerType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Player'

  field :id, !types.ID
  field :birth_date, Types::DateTimeType
  field :death_date, Types::DateTimeType
  field :note, types.String
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [source code](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/719b5eda918d71ce7e6695939653f2371f95e607/lib/graphql/define/type_definer.rb), there are only 5 types(Int, String, Float, Boolean, ID) defined as method which means you cannot use `types.DateTime`.

To customize DateTimeType, you could reference its [document](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/graphql/1.7.8/GraphQL/ScalarType) of the gem and implement as the above you've mentioned about (**date_time_type.rb**), then you can use it like this:

`field :birth_date, Types::DateTimeType`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have a better explanation, but I did get it to work by pasting the code from above to define my own scalar `DateTimeType`:

```
DateTimeType = GraphQL::ScalarType.define do
  name 'DateTime'

  coerce_input ->(value, _ctx) { Time.zone.parse(value) }
  coerce_result ->(value, _ctx) { value.utc.iso8601 }
end

MyType = ::GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'MyType'
  field :when, type: !DateTimeType
end
```